# matlab2012a stuck at 'busy' after clear mex

Tags: matlab, memory-leaks, mex

I have a mex compiled using Visual Studio with Matlab 2012a
The mex logic is:

- create a 3d volume (memory allocation)
- project a volume into an image
- delete the volume (free memory)

when I call the mex and clear it  (**using Matlab 2012a**) the Matlab gets stuck on 'Busy' state.

When I run the same mex file from Matlab 2019 this problem doesnt appear.

I checked and the memory the mex allocate is being freed before I clear the mex

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you recompile the MEX-file with each version of MATLAB?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I compiled using 2012 because I thought that would solve the issue, it didnt. previous compilation was using 2017

Comment: @JamesTursa I can write a toy code which resembles it, it would take a few days

Comment: Isn't this basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55438352/681865) again?